# Trying to understand css selectors, id in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I need some help understanding how this code works and what it returns. I haven't coded this myself, but I think I can use this to solve my problem if I get the understanding of it.

**Code:**

```
var bedText1 = '4-bed inside cabin';
var selectors = '.cabin-item .cabin-prices select[data-cabin-name="' + bedText1 + '"]';

browser.elements('css selector', selectors, function (result) {
    browser.assert.equal(result.value.length > 0, true, "expect to find at least one 4-bed cabin");
    console.log(result.value.length);
    console.log(result.value);
    browser.elementIdClick(result.value[0].ELEMENT + ' option[value="' + cabin4 + '"]');
});
```

result.value.length returns:

```
[ ELEMENT: '26',
ELEMENT: '27',
ELEMENT: '28',
ELEMENT: '29',
ELEMENT: '30' ]
```

I need to get the id from one of these elements, which has being found. Does any one know if this is possible?

Comment: `this.elements`? Anyone have any idea what library this would be?

Comment: its nightwatch.. (browser.elements)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Have you tried to run the code? What is the expected result?

Comment: I has nothing to do with nightwatch, Just trying to get the id from the elements i have found

Comment: Would it be possible for you to `console.log(result)`? If you want to get the ID from it, chances are it's a property in the element.